# How to join group in Telegram group based on an invite code

Tags: telegram

Someone provide this: tg://join?invite=EaEnSUPktgfoI-xxxxxxxx

1. How do I join that group in web based version of Telegram?
2. I tried that link in my Chrome browser but it just did a Google search.

These are the menu options in the web-based Telegram.

[image]

Comment: copy the link into a chat, e.g. message yourself. After you send the message, you can klick on the link and follow the invitaion.

(This is obviously an answer - it seems impossible for me to post a proper answer to this question)

Comment: @chichak This worked! Not clear why you can't post an answer?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: good to hear! I don't know why I can't post an answer, maybe on this stackexchange you need more points then I have for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another post with the link to join like this: https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEQbOeucnaMWN0A9dQ

Then when I clicked I chose "Open in web", and then clicked "Join" button at the bottom, and then showed this URL: https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@EOSproject

Comment: This is not working anymore, like the other answer (at least for channels instead of groups). But I added another answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the URL to the form `https://telegram.me/joinchat/<group-identifier>` where `<group-identifier>` is the piece of string after `invite=` and you should be able to join from the web messenger.

In your case the link would be https://telegram.me/joinchat/EaEnSUPktgfoI-XPfMYtcQ

Comment: Telegram.me is not found.  My URL is currently: https://web.telegram.org/#/im, 

What is the tg://join link??

Comment: telegram.me works fine for me, @NealWalters. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6MA.png `tg://` protocol is handled by the telegram desktop appl

Comment: As of April 2019, this just redirects to the tg://join?invite= link I can't open...

Answer (score 1):

Joining a channel invite on Telegram was not working anymore on the web version even with the answers already shared but I found another way to do it (the solution may work on groups also).

First you need a valid invite link but if you don't have one and want to test, you can probably find one on Twitter or other websites by searching "telegram invite".

Then I noticed that an invite link was shared on a channel @LaMenaceYT and the HTML source code of the link shared looks like this:

```
<a class="anchor-url" href="https://t.me/+pKrHzj5V9rA2OGZk" onclick="joinchat(this)"><strong>https://t.me/+pKrHzj5V9rA2OGZk</strong></a>
```

So it is possible to join another channel invite by using a JavaScript code like this with another link I found on Twitter, by executing the code in the web console (F12 shortcut or directly Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox) when you are on Telegram web version:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "https://t.me/+L8x0cOvDGBA3Y2Vi";
joinchat(link);
```

For people who are curious, here is what the source code of the JavaScript function joinchat looks like, found by typing `joinchat.toString()`:

```
"t=>{(0,ce.Z)(null);let i,s,n=t.href;const a=new URL(n),o=a.host.match(/(.+?)\\.t(?:elegram)?\\.me/);o&&(a.pathname=o[1]+(\"/\"===a.pathname?\"\":a.pathname),n=a.toString()),e.noPathnameParams||(i=new URL(n).pathname.split(\"/\").slice(1)),e.noUriParams||(s=this.parseUriParams(n));const r=e.callback({pathnameParams:i,uriParams:s},t);return void 0===r&&r}"
```

When I tested, it also worked on a channel invite where the admin has to approve the request (Telegram account of a YouTube channel: https://t.me/+SYCDhioqnRg3ZDZk) even if there was a JavaScript error "[API] Error 400 INVITE_REQUEST_SENT" when trying to join multiple times.

Comment: This currently works in the K version of telegram web.